# Is it possible to parse contents of push notification and insert in to SQLIte whilst app is in background or killed?

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that receives data via push messages. I parse the data from the push message and insert it into a SQLite Database...   I have noticed that the new data is not inserted into the database..

Is it possible to achieve this?

I've searched around and the and the answers are very conflicting and a little confusing.      Further information would be greatly appreciated.